# Inject service into an AutoMapper destination class

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, automapper

Say I have a source and destination class that is mapped using AutoMapper.
The destination has a logger service injected into the constructor.

However, I don't know how to get the service injected into the constructor through StructureMap?

I've tried the following:

```
Mapper.Initialize(m =>
 {                
    m.ConstructServicesUsing(ObjectFactory.GetInstance);
 });
```

which didn't prevent me having the exception on the mapping call, I guess because the service isn't being injected in properly.

I also tried the following:

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
 .ConstructUsing(x=> ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILoggerService>());
```

But I get the error: **cannot convert Lamda expression to delegate type**, yet all the examples I have seen use this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lambda you pass into ConstructUsing  must return an instance of the destination type.  So in your case, you would want to do this:

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>()  
.ConstructUsing(x=> ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Dest>());
```

Assuming you have StructureMap setup correctly, it should create the Dest object and inject the ILoggerService for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this:

```
        Mapper.Configuration.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve);

        Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>().ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
```

Comment: Out of interest, would this be faster than the selected answer since the object is just resolved instead of going through the factory?